# Color change HTML

Tags: html

I would like an `<input type="text">`, if the values are greater than 50 then the text should appear in green, is the value between 25 and 50 orange and less than 25 red.

But I don't know how to make it work exactly can someone help me with such an HTML file?

```
<body>
<form>
  <label for="fname">Value</label>
  <input type="text" id="value" name="value">
</form>
if value is less than 25 > red,
if value is between 25 - 50 > orange, 
if value is greater than 50 > green.
</body>
```

Comment: you need to show your code, then only we will able to help you.https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's not possible only with HTML, you have to use JS for this type of operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although it's best to try and you should show your attempts, I assume you're stuck and cannot figure it out on your own. Below is a simple demonstration, if you enter a number in the input field which is below `25` it appears red, between `25-50`, orange, and above, it appears green.

It would be better if you can use this example to implement your understanding now, or customise this as you wish.

```js
const input = document.getElementById('number')

input.onkeyup = function () {
  let value = Number(input.value)
  if (value < 25) input.style.color = "red"

  // Here we check as long as the number is above 25, but below 50, we update to orange.
  if (value > 25 && value <= 50) input.style.color = "orange"
  if (value > 50) input.style.color = "green"
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number">
```

Comment: Thx! And how exactly do you do it with three colors? I tried 
'if (Number(input.value) < 50 & > 20) input.style.color = "green"'
But this doesn't work.

Comment: And how exactly do you do it with three colors? I tried 
'if (Number(input.value) < 50 & > 20) input.style.color = "green"'
But this doesn't work.

Comment: Please check my answer now, show be exactly what you asked.

Comment: Second and third if should be "else if". There is no need to check this anymore if the first one (or second) is true. AND most important, the second if, should be:
`if (value >= 25 && value <= 50){}` Otherwise, 25 will still become red (even due this should not be regarding your reqs!

Answer (score 1):

This jquery example will come in handy.

```js
$("#myinput").keyup(function() {
  var myvalue = $(this).val();
  if (myvalue <= 25) {
    var color = "red";
  } else if (myvalue > 25 && myvalue <= 50) { 
    var color = "orange";
  } else {
    var color = "green";
  }
  $(this).attr("style", "color:" + color);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="myinput">
```